# Why this snippet gives "type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type of string"?

Tags: flutter

Here I am trying to get RSS data from a website using WebFeed. The data should be loaded as soon as the page loads (or if there is a better solution). I tried some suggestions from Stackoverflow but could not make it work. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:webfeed/webfeed.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GetNews extends StatefulWidget {
 u/override
 _GetNewsState createState() => _GetNewsState();
}

class _GetNewsState extends State<GetNews> {
 String newvar;

 u/override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
    newvar = load();
  }

 u/override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Text(newvar)),
      ),
    );
  }

 Future<String> getInfo() async {
 String link = 'https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/rss';
 var client = http.Client();
 var response = await client.get(link);
 var feed = RssFeed.parse(response.body);
 String author = feed.items.first.author;
 return author;
  }

 load() async {
 return await getInfo();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every **async** function is a **Future** in Flutter. You are assigning a Future function to a String variable. That is what the error is saying. Your code should look something like this.

```
String newvar = "";
//
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  this.getInfo();
}
//
getInfo() async {
  String link = 'https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/rss';
  var client = http.Client();
  var response = await client.get(link);
  var feed = RssFeed.parse(response.body);
  String author = feed.items.first.author;
  this.setState({
    newvar = author;
  });
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying, "'data != null': A non-null String must be provided to a text widget."

Comment: Did you initialize the `newvar ` variable as shown in my code? If yes, then the variable `author ` holds a null a value.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion works. Issue was with the feed.items.first.author where author brings null value, because the website RSS does not hold a value for author directly. I had to use item.dc.creator to access author name. Thank you for your help.